# How To Create Constraint between one field of one table, to two field of two table in sql

Tags: sql, constraints

Table1:
    field:ID1

Table2:
    field:ID2

Table3:
    field:ID3

I want constraint: ID3 in (ID1 + ID2)

Actually Should ID3 exist in ID1 , if not exist, Should ID3 exist in ID2

Example:

ID1{1,3,5}
ID2{6,7}

Note: *ID1 And ID2 Can Not Have Common Data*

ID3 can contains {1,3,5,6,7}

Comment: You can write a trigger to achive it because computed column can be created within the table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What is `+` in `I want constraint: ID3 in (ID1 + ID2)` ? Should ID3 exist in *both* ID1 and ID2, or in *either*, or in *any* ??

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Primary Key In Table 1 And Table 2 And Use referential key Into table3 so table3 has only those records which table1 and table2 have.